# How to rename a file by editing its current name?

Tags: emacs, elisp

For example: I have a file `longest_substring_no_repeating_chars.cc`. One day I want to rename it to `longest_substr_no_repeating_chars.cc`. How do I do it by editing the old name? Or is there any convenient way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to rename the file you're currently editing you can define a function like this one:

```
(defun rename-file-and-buffer ()
  "Renames current buffer and file it is visiting."
  (interactive)
  (let ((name (buffer-name))
        (filename (buffer-file-name)))
    (if (not (and filename (file-exists-p filename)))
        (message "Buffer '%s' is not visiting a file!" name)
      (let ((new-name (read-file-name "New name: " filename)))
        (cond ((get-buffer new-name)
               (message "A buffer named '%s' already exists!" new-name))
              (t
               (rename-file name new-name 1)
               (rename-buffer new-name)
               (set-visited-file-name new-name)
               (set-buffer-modified-p nil)))))))
```

And the you can bind it to a key combo like <kbd>C-c r</kbd>

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c r") 'rename-file-and-buffer)
```

Otherwise, @Oleg's suggestion to use `dired` is a great option.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in dired mode. `R` shortcut invokes dired-do-rename where you
can press <kbd>down</kbd> to get back the old name.

It's even easier if you use dired-x, just add to your init file.

```
(require 'dired-x)
```

Then you can press <kbd>C-x C-j R</kbd>  to edit as you need to, then
<kbd>q</kbd> to go back to your buffer.

Another possibility: `M-x wdired-change-to-wdired-mode`. In this mode you can
edit files directly. Press `C-c C-c` when you want to commit your changes or
`C-c ESC` to cancel them.

Comment: In dired-mode you can type the familiar `toggle-read-only` binding `C-x C-q` to call `dired-toggle-read-only` which is a more convenient way to invoke `wdired-change-to-wdired-mode`.